# How to prove that if $A\subseteq B$and $|A|=|B|$, then $A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Apart from the question in the title, the other question that related to the first question: Define: $f(X)=${$f(x)|x\in X$}. if $X$ is finite, $f(X)\subset X$ and $f$ is one to one, then $|f(X)|=|X|$, and according to the statement in the first question, $f(X)=X$. Then if $X$ is infinite, why could it be that $f(X)\neq X$ even if $f$ is one to one? 

Note:"$|A|$" represents the number of elements in the set A.

Comment: Of course, we have to read $A \subset B$ in the tiltle, as $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: Consider $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, where $f(n)=n+1$. Is this one-to-one? Is this onto?

Comment: it's one to one but not onto

Comment: See [Finite set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) and [Dedekind-infinite set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).

Comment: ok, roger that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are *infinite*, we may have $|A|=|B|$ but still $A \ne B$.

Let $A=\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,2,... \}$ and $B = \{ 0,2,4,...\}$; we have the one-to-one mapping (but **not** onto) $f : A \rightarrow B$ such that $f(n)=2n$ (Galileo dicovered it), but clearly $A \ne B$ ($B \subset A$, with *proper* inclusion).

Answer (score -1):

$$
\text{First, I think your question is wrong}
$$
$$
A\subset B\quad \text{should be}\quad A\subseteq B
$$

$$
\text{Here is my proof}
$$
$$\text{Assume } A \neq B$$
$$\because A \subseteq B$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall a \in A \mid a \in B \tag{1}$$
$$A \neq B \tag{2}$$
$$(1)\quad \text{and} \quad (2)\Rightarrow \exists b \in B \mid b \notin \tag{3}A$$
$$(1)\quad and\quad(3) \Rightarrow\vert A \vert \neq \vert B \vert $$
$$\Rightarrow \text{Our assumption is false}$$
$$\Rightarrow A = B$$

Comment: what is the differences between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$? And why should I use $\subseteq$?

Comment: if $A \subset B$ then at least one element in B and the element is not in A, so $\vert A \vert$ never equals $\vert B \vert$

Comment: How you prove that : from $A \subseteq B$, i.e. $\forall a (a \in A \rightarrow a \in B)$, **and** $A \ne B$, i.e. $\exists b (b \in B \land b \notin A)$, then $|A| \ne |B|$ follows ?

Comment: well, since there is at least one element in B, but not in A, so the size of B > the size of A, (1) and (2) imply that

Comment: You forget the condition that $A$ and $B$ must be *finite* ... What is "size" ? Cardinality ? How we prove it ? With a bijection between the set $A$ and the set $\{ 1,2,..., n \}$ for some natural number $n$ ?.

Comment: If you *define* the "size" of a *finite* set $A$ through a *bijection* $b_A: A \rightarrow \{1,2,...,n \}$, for some natural number $n$, from the fact that $|A|=|B|$ we have two bijections $b_A$ and $b_B$ to the "same" $n$. Now, from the *assumption* that $\exists x(x \in B \land x \notin A)$, we have that $b_B(x)=k$, for some $k \le n$. Then consider $b_A^{-1}(k)$; it must exists:call it $y$. $y \in A$, so $y \in B$. But if $y \ne x$ we have that two elements of $B$ are mapped into the same $k$, contrary to bijection. And if $y = x$ we have that $x \notin A$ and $x \in A$: contradiction.

Comment: It is not correct to say that "$A\subset B$" means that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$.  Some authors use that symbol that way, but many — very many — use it to mean merely that $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: $\subset \quad$ is proper subset is standard symbol for set, I did not know why those authors use $\subset$ to represents $\subseteq$